# Javascript regex for plain numbers or numbers ending in percent

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in need of a regex that validates only plain numbers, or numbers ending in a percent. I have tried the following:

```
/(?!\%$)(\D)/
```

Which I believe looks for any non-digit excluding an ending percent sign. When I test it, it always returns the same result no matter what though:

http://jsfiddle.net/zow37wLq/1/

Comment: post some examples for valid and invalid matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is with your code, not with your regex. See line 9 in your code:

```
// Set New Image Width
$('#photo-width').on('input', function () {
    var newWidth = $('#photo-width').attr('value'),
        // attempted regex to find any non-digits excluding an ending percent.
        reg = /(?!\%$)(\D)/,
        charTest = reg.test(newWidth);

    // if formatting is incorrect
    if (charTest = true) { // <-------------------------- THIS
        $('.debug').html('<b>Result</b> Please enter only numbers or percents.');
    // if formatting is OK
    } else {
        $('.debug').html('<b>Result</b> Looks OK');
    }
});
```

The line needs to be needs to be `if (charTest == true) {`

[See updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zow37wLq/7/)

Comment: Uuuuughhh... if you knew how long I was messing with this thinking the regex was the problem...

Answer (score 2):

This regex should work:

`/^\d+%?$/`

**ohaal** figured out the problem, but why are you searching for everything that doesn't match instead of searching for what does?

Comment: Your regex matches an empty string. `\d+` seems better.

Comment: Yeah. I was originally trying the regex to test for what does work, but since I thought it wasn't functioning, I tried it the other way around.

Comment: @PeterHerdenborg doh. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:
[0-9]+((px{1}|%{1}))

i usually test my regexp in the following site:

https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: I don't think that regex does what you think it does. The {1} quantifier is meaningless, as "one match" is the default if you don't use a quantifier. The % is optional, so ? would be the correct quantifier. Also, the grouping parenthesis make no sense.

Comment: i know the {1} issue, just a precaution . However in the jsfiddle, he is trying to use both % and px.